# Search in UITableView - NSInvalidArgumentException error

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm implementing the search bar in a UITableView (tblFriends) with a "SearchBar and search Display controller"

This is my NSarray of dictionaries filteredFriendsList (equal to friendsList NSarray):

```
            {
        gender
        id
        name
        picture
```

}

I have the table view in a UIViewController, (not in a tableViewController) because the table occupies only half view.

This is the code:
INTERFACE:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ClasseSingleton.h"
#import "FBConnect.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{

    NSArray *friendsList;
    NSDictionary *friendsDict;

    NSMutableArray *filteredFriendsList;

    IBOutlet UITableView *tblFriends;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *friendsList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *filteredFriendsList;

-(void)getFriends;


@end
```

IMPLEMENTATION

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize friendsList, filteredFriendsList;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [tblFriends setDelegate:self];
    [tblFriends setDataSource:self];


}

- (void)getFriends{

    NSLog(@"ENTRATO - getFriends");

    //Copy ARRAY in other ARRAY
    friendsList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[ClasseSingleton getFriends]];

    filteredFriendsList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[ClasseSingleton getFriends]];


    NSLog(@"getFriends : DESCRIPTION\n\n %@", [friendsList description]);
    NSLog(@"Count friendslist: %i", [friendsList count]);

    [tblFriends reloadData];

}


//                  *****TABLE MANAGEMENT*****                 //


//Nuber of cells
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    NSLog(@"tabella1");
    return [filteredFriendsList count];


}

//Populate the table
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPat{

    static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    //Set Style cell
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }

    friendsDict = [filteredFriendsList objectAtIndex:indexPat.row];


    //Set CELL TEXT
    NSString *cellValue = [friendsDict objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSLog(@"TBL %@", cellValue);
    [cell.textLabel setText:cellValue];
    return cell;

}

//                          SEARCH IN TABLE

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption{

    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)saearchBar {
    [self.filteredFriendsList removeAllObjects];
    [self.filteredFriendsList addObjectsFromArray: friendsList];
}


- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{

    /*
     Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
     */
    [self.filteredFriendsList removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.

    /*
     Search the main list for products whose type matches the scope (if selected) and whose name matches searchText; add items that match to the filtered array.
     */
    NSString *cellTitle;
    for (cellTitle in friendsList){
    //    for (cellTitle in [friendsDict objectForKey:@"name"]){    
        NSComparisonResult result = [cellTitle compare:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame){
            [filteredFriendsList addObject:cellTitle];
        }
    }
}

...

@end
```

Everytime i put some character in the search bar the app crashes with this error:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary compare:options:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I hope to solve the problem, it's the 6th days with this error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You declare `filteredFriendsList` to be a `NSMutableArray`, but you're assigning an immuatble `NSArray` to it here:

```
filteredFriendsList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[ClasseSingleton getFriends]];
```

Change it to this:

```
filteredFriendsList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[ClasseSingleton getFriends]];
```

Comment: or `[[ClasseSingleton getFriends] mutableCopy]`

Comment: :( Now there is a new error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary compare:options:range:]:

Comment: This is the whole ERROR:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary compare:options:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c84630'

Comment: @yuji The problem is here, in filterContentForSearchText method: NSString *cellTitle;
 for (cellTitle in friendsList){
    //    for (cellTitle in [friendsDict objectForKey:@"name"]){    
  NSComparisonResult result = [cellTitle compare:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
  if (result == NSOrderedSame){
   [filteredFriendsList addObject:cellTitle];
  }

Comment: `friendsList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[ClasseSingleton getFriends]];` this doesn't make sense: `getFriends` doesn't return `NSArray`. Its return type is `void`.

Comment: @yuji No, getFriends is a my method, it's return a NSMutableArray. I Made a NSLOG of [friendList description] and i have the expected result.

Comment: Okay, well you need to change it to `friendsList = `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:...]`, and also you need to make sure that the contents of `friendsList` are the right kind of object.

Comment: @yuji Yespica, i've Made it, but nothing. I think the problem is in filterContentForSearchText method.